# Assembly endless loop [HOMEWORK]

Tags: loops, assembly, masm, irvine32

I am working on a homework assignment where I need to randomly print 20 lines of 20 RANDOM characters to the screen. I am extremely new to assembly language and don't understand why my loop won't end, even though I have ecx set to 20 and am decrementing each time.

currently the screen prints the random letters correctly, but never stops printing.

My code is as follow:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
    .data
         buffer byte 20 dup(?) ;buffer of size 20 initialized ?
         L dword 20     ;length of size 20
    .code

    main proc

        l1:
            mov ecx,L ;ecx = 20
            call RandomString   ;call Random String
            dec ecx   ;ecx --
            cmp ecx,0 ;compare ecx to zero
            jne l1    ;jump if not equal back to l1

            call WaitMsg   ;press any button to continue

    exit
    main endp

   RandomString PROC USES eax ecx edx
       mov eax,26     ;eax = 26
       call RandomRange    ;call RandomRange
       add eax, 'A'   ;eax = random number between 0 and 25 + 'A'
       mov  buffer,al ;buffer = random letter
       mov edx, OFFSET buffer   ;edx = address of buffer
       call WriteString    ;write string to console

   ret
   RandomString ENDP

   end main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep resetting ecx:

```
    l1:
        mov ecx,L ;ecx = 20   <--set ecx to 20
        call RandomString   
        dec ecx   ;ecx --     <--ecx is now 19
        cmp ecx,0 ;compare ecx to zero
        jne l1                <-- jump to l1, and ecx becomes 20 again
```

You should move the `mov` to BEFORE the `l1` label:

```
        mov ecx,L ;ecx = 20
    l1:
        call RandomString   ;call Random String
        dec ecx   ;ecx --
        cmp ecx,0 ;compare ecx to zero
        jne l1
```

Comment: perfect! that was exactly it! Much appreciated!

Comment: @GreenFerret95 when someone provides a meaningful answer, you should mark it as such, that way when other readers look at the list of questions they can easily identify ones that have answers. If there is more than one answer too, the one you've selected will show up immediately below your question.